# Accessing the navigationController from a 'push'ed viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a main menu using a UITableView which can successfully push and display other ViewControllers to the fore. However, within these pushed controllers I wish to be able to push other controllers onto the navigationController stack. `self.navigationController` in a pushed ViewController seemingly does not reference anything, so when I do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];` nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post the according code?

Comment: The way to do this is definitely using self.navigationController. Please post the code that does the first push onto the navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

class a{

from here u pushed to class b

so

while pushed to class b

before push specify

classbObject.classaNav=self.navigationController;

then push it.

}

class b{

declare

Navigation controller here

UINavigationcontroller *classaNav;

in view did load u can access the classaNav

}

cheers!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it has something to do with animation. Set the animated property to NO and then try. Also, please post your code.